# Copy my data from a existing db to a new db

Tags: mysql, backup

I have a database which has my data's that I have been working for months. Now, I want to delete that db. What concern's me is that the data's that I have might come in handy in the future development. So I want to get a backup for this db, where I can get all the data's and table structures in this db as a backup and then delete it.

I am confused about how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this one.

```
 mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [databasename] > [backupfile.sql]    
    [username] - this is your database username
    [password] - this is the password for your database
    [databasename] - the name of your database
    [backupfile.sql] - the file to which the backup should be written.
```

[URL](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Backing-up-and-restoring-your-MySQL-Database/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `mysql_dump` dump utility ([MySQL docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)).

Alternatively you can use the `Export` function of PhpMyAdmin to generate a SQL file containing all you structure and data.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump database_name` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

And it would even be much simpler if you have xampp or wampp,because all you would need to do is to export the whole database